# A graph with a few number of edges has a big subgraph with low degree vertices

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, probabilistic-method

Suppose $G$ is a graph that $|E(G)| \leq \epsilon |G|^2$, prove that there is $H \subset G$ such that $|H| \geq |G|/2$ and for all $v \in H$ we have 
$d_H(v) \leq 4 \epsilon |H| $.

$|G|$ is the number of vertices in $G$.
$E(G)$ is the set of edges in $G$.
$d_H(v)$ is the number of vertices in $H$ connected to $v$.

I tried to solve it by applying probabilistic method, but I failed.
Easily you can find such $H$ that for all $v \in H$ we have 
$d_H(v) \leq 8 \epsilon |H| $.but about $4$...

Is there any hint?

Thanks.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe It is not obvious to me why $H$ must have size $|G|/2$. Note that for larger $H$, the upper bound $2 \epsilon |H|$ is looser, so potentially there may be some gain in considering larger $H$. Note also that the degree $d_H$ only considers neighbors in $H$.

Comment: I've been wondering what is the minimum $|E(G)|$ of edges to satisfy that for all $H\subset G$, $|H|\geq|G|/2$, there exists a vertex $v\in H$ with $d_H(v)>2\epsilon |H|$. Feels like an optimization problem.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe would you pls notice the edition?

Comment: Hopefully that means a contradiction is easier? I couldn't find a contradiction with $d_H(v)>2\epsilon|H|$.

Comment: @ZhuoranHe , yes,i have to prove sth easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No probabilistic method is necessary; a greedy algorithm is enough.

Start by taking $H = G$. For as long as there is a vertex $v$ with $\deg_H v > 4 \epsilon |H|$, delete $v$ from $H$.

This cannot be done more than $\frac12|G|$ times. For as long as $|H| \ge \frac12 |G|$, each time we delete a vertex, we lose more than $4 \epsilon |H| \ge 2 \epsilon |G|$ edges, so if we delete $\frac12 |G|$ vertices, we have lost more than $2\epsilon |G| \cdot \frac12 |G| = \epsilon |G|^2$  edges: more than the total number of edges in $G$.

So we have to stop sometime before then. When we stop, we still have more than $\frac12 |G|$ vertices left in $H$, but no vertex can be deleted: all vertices have $\deg_H v \le 4\epsilon|H|$.

We could actually be more careful than this, and get a maximum degree of $\frac83 \epsilon |H|$, by observing that if we keep deleting vertices that violate this property, then after $\frac12|G|$ steps we delete at least
$$\frac83 \epsilon |G| + \frac83 \epsilon (|G|-1) + \dots + \frac83 \epsilon \left(\frac12|G|+1\right) > \epsilon |G|^2$$ edges. (In other words, keep track of $|H|$ when seeing how many edges we lose, rather than using the bound $|H| \ge \frac12 |G|$ at each step.)